# C# - winforms - getting texts of specific column in listview in form of an array

Tags: c#, winforms, arrays, listview

is it possible to get the text values of specific column in a listview in form of array without using a loop function? lets say I have a listview contains 2 columns and 5000 records. what I want is to get all the texts under column 2 only but without using a loop. I know I can accomplish this with a loop but it takes ages if I had 5000+ records..

any ideas?

Comment: What's the source of the data that's in the control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel your pain and I've personally experienced how slow a `ListViewItemsCollection` can be.

You **can** access the second column of a `ListView` without a for loop like this:

```
string[] column1 = this.listView1.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Select(item => item.SubItems[1].Text).ToArray();
```

but this isn't any faster than a for loop.  In fact it's a little bit slower!  Other tricks like trying to use `ListViewItemsCollection.CopyTo` also fail miserably.

A major problem with the `ListView` is that is pathologically slow when used as a data structure.  The property `ListView.Items` **looks** like a data structure and you can **use** it like a data structure but any way you slice it:

- data goes in but it *doesn't come out fast*.

So if you follow alexD's advice you will find that a **real** data structure will outperform a `ListViewItemCollection` by orders of magnitude.  The moral of the story is if you want to query the data in a `ListViewItemCollection` fast, you have no alternative than to keep a fast copy **outside** of the `ListView`.  Practically any data structure will do, e.g.

- a `string[][]`
- a `string[,]`
- a `List<List<string>>`
- a `List<string[]>` or even
- a `List<Tuple<string, string>>`.

These can all store the same data as a two-column `ListView` and will be instantaneously fast by comparison to using the `ListView` as a data structure.  It is inconvenient but that is the price we must pay for speed.

Comment: thanks for clearing this.. I thought there is a good way to do that.. anyway I will just use another thread to do the whole loop.. i think its the easiest way to do that..

Comment: That's a good idea but unfortunately you cannot use another thread to speed it up because background threads are not allowed to access WinForms user interface objects like `ListView`.

Comment: I will just copy ListViewItems from the ListView control to an array.. then pass that array to a new thread.. that's it.. Just implemented it and its really working like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't read the data directly from the text file into the list view...store it in a data structure like an `ArrayList` which will maintain the order in which you insert elements.

Comment: mate I'm reading the data from text file only once (when the program runs)... so this is not the problem..

Comment: Yes, but if you read it into a data structure first, then you don't need to worry about pulling the column out of the ListView later on.  You've got your array of strings from the getgo.